# Anova violates normality assumption for error data

Tags: anova, data-transformation, nonparametric, normality-assumption, robust

I have a 2 x 2 repeated measures ANOVA (N = 51) with Error Rate data as the dependent measure. The error data violates the normality assumption, even when outliers are removed. I have looked at the square root and sin transformations but the assumption is still violated with these. I used the shaprio test and viewed the qq-plots. For the shapiro test, the ps < .05 for most of the unique conditions. But the qq-plots look pretty good (follow the line) for all but one of the unique conditions.

I know that the anova is also robust to violations of normality -- but there also seems to be two camps: one who views this violation as fine and another who does not. The non-parametric tests are really only for one-way anovas, and not for a more complex 2x2 design.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do next? The analysis interpretation with the non-transformed and transformed data (with and without outliers) does not change, which suggest some convergence.

If you have any advice, resources, or tips, please let me know!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "error rate data"?  This sounds like you might be trying to analyze some kind of summary statistics in a situation where it would be better to analyze the original data directly.

Comment: It's the error rate (inverse would be accuracy). Basically, their response was either correct (1) or incorrect (0). I am using all of the raw data for each trial. Is that more clear? @whuber

Comment: @johnconnor Would it be fair to say that your data are reported as binary correct/incorrect?

Comment: It's becoming clearer, but the term "error rate" is confusing: you might be observing the actual *errors* as the raw data, not their rates.  The errors often can effectively be analyzed with a logistic regression, which automatically handles the heteroscedasticity you are seeing.

Comment: yes, you are right. I shouldn't have said error rate. I'm using their actual error scores. Okay, so I can run a logistic regression on the data, and not worry about the violation. I will give that a try today. Thank you for your help on this @whuber

Comment: Please edit your question to add the new information in comments. We prefer posts to be self-contained, besides, comments are easily overseen and can be deleted!